# Loop not looping

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, foreach

So I have a bunch of users what I need to display. I'm getting the users from a database, then displaying them. Here's how I'm doing that

```
//Get users from DB
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM followers where follow_to = :user");
$stmt->bindValue(':user', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

//Place results in an array 
$posts = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $posts =  array(
        'follow_from' => $row['follow_from']
        );
    }   

//And loop users 
foreach($posts as $post) {
        $post;
?>
<?php 
//Display users 
echo $posts['follow_from']; }
?>
```

Now the issue is, I only get *one* result returned. So if I have more then one result, it gets overridden. Any help would be nice.

Comment: you are always redefining your array.. of course it will contain only one post :) `$posts =  array([...])`

Comment: Can't you output within your loop?

Comment: That’s because you are _overwriting_ `$posts` in each loop iteration …

Comment: `$posts[] = $row['follow_from']` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$posts = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $posts[$row['follow_from']] =  1;
    }   


foreach($posts as $key => $useless) {

//Display users 
echo $key; }
```

Comment: Why must you add the `$useless`?

Comment: in a foreach loop you can't just name the `$key`. if you give only one argument, it will be the `$value` http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, but didn't post in an answer, you are creating a new array each loop instead of appending or "pushing" the value into the $posts array.

```
$posts = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $posts[] =  array(
    'follow_from' => $row['follow_from']
    );
}   

foreach($posts as $post) {
    // $post is equal to $posts[n] where n is the index of the current loop 0,1,2,...
    echo $post['follow_from'];
}
```

?>

You will notice that I added `[]` to the end of `$posts` which will insert a new numerical element with the data. You can also use `array_push()` but it's often slower.

The above code will output an array that looks similar to the following.

```
$posts = array(
   array('follow_from',data),
   array('follow_from',data),
   array('follow_from',data),
   ...
);
```

As for an example of appending values to an array, you can look at the following code.

```
$array = array('value 1');
$array[] = 'value 2';
array_push($array,'value 3');
print_r($array);

/*
 Array(
   [0] = "value 1"
   [1] = "value 2"
   [2] = "value 3"
 )
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `$row['follow_from']` within your while loop.
However, based on what you are currently doing, you may like to populate your posts array directly with   [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

```
$posts = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($posts as $post) { 
    echo $post['follow_from']; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code use `fetchAll()` instead of `fetch()`

Comment: I then get `Undefined index: follow_from `

Comment: @Idris because `fetchAll` doesn't return the same array structure as `fetch` (you could see the right structure with `var_dump` or `var_export`) ;)